# Appscripts won't open URLs from spreadsheet correctly in new tabs (target="_blank")

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I want to open the URLs from my spreadsheet in a new tab. The URLs for documents in my Drive work, but the .pdfs that are on external websites do not. The tab opens with the correct URL in it but the page doesn't load. If I copy the URL then paste it into a new tab it does work.

```
var link = urlFromSpreadsheet;

idLink.append('<div value="hLink"><a href="'+link+'"target="_blank">Link</a></div>');
```

Most of my URLs are .pdfs and work with the download attribute just not target="_blank". My Drive URLs don't work with the download attribute.

```
idLink.append('<div value="hLink"><a href="'+link+'"download>Link</a></div>');
```

Comment: Do you have the links within a cell of the spreadsheet? Are you opening the links using appscript? Finally, where are you retrieving the links from (I am assuming the files are hosted on your Drive account)?

Comment: The links are in cells on the spreadsheet. I'm using an embedded appscript on a Google site to retrieve the link from the spreadsheet. Some links are files hosted in my drive account  while others are links to other websites.